# Limit of the solution to a SDE

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to learn about SDEs and I don't seem to understand this claim:

Assume $X_t$ is the strong solution to the following SDE:
\begin{equation}
dX_t=c\tanh X_t \, dt +dB_t
\end{equation}
Where $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion and $c>0$ is a constant.

The claim is to prove that with probability $1$,
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|X_t|}{t}=c
\end{equation}
**What I know so far:

Since $|\tanh x|\leq 1$ for any $x$ and using the fact that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_t}{t}=0$ w.p. $1$, we can see that

\begin{equation}
\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|X_t|}{t}\leq c
\end{equation}

Also, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $Y_n=X_n-X_{n-1}$. Therefore:

\begin{equation}
|Y_n|\geq |B_n-B_{n-1}|-c
\end{equation}
So for any $M>0$, there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $|Y_n|>2M$ and consequently, there exist infinitely many $t$ such that $|X_t|>M$.

Now, let $M>0$ and  define $t_+$ to be the amount of time up to time $t$ that $X_t>M$ and $t_-$ be the amount of time up to time $t$ that $X_t<-M$. I think what I need to show is that either $\frac{t_+}{t}\rightarrow 1$ or $\frac{t_-}{t}\rightarrow 1$. But I don't seem to know how.

Answer (score 0):

We set $Y_{t}:=X_{1/t}$, then we study

$$\limsup_{t\to 0}tY_{t}=\limsup_{t\to 0}tB_{1/t}+c\limsup_{t\to 0}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh(Y_{st})}{s^{2}}ds.$$

The first term goes to zero by time-inversion. So the challenge is showing that

$$\limsup_{t\to +\infty}\tanh(X_{st})=1, \forall s\geq 1.$$

If we had $\limsup_{t\to +\infty}X_{t}=\ell<\infty$, then

$$\limsup_{t\to +\infty}B_{t+1}-B_{t}=\limsup_{t\to +\infty}\left(X_{t+1}-X_{t}-c\int_{0}^{1}\tanh(X_{t+s})ds\right)<+\infty.$$

This contradicts a (Hewitt–Savage 0-1 law)-computation showing that for each fixed $M>0$, we have $B_{n+1}-B_{n}>M$ for some subsequence $n$.